# Usage of "slf4j.api" in an OSGi bundle requires extender "osgi.serviceloader.processor" after update to 2.x

Tags: java, osgi, slf4j, service-provider, bnd

I have created a small reproducer project on GitHub: [slf4j-experiment](https://github.com/jmini/bnd-experiments/tree/37293af220e02ab388af622301117bda2e72507c/slf4j-experiment)

Basically all I need is an OSGi bundle where some code is using `slf4j-api`.

Example:

```java
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Activate;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Deactivate;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@Component(service = SomeService.class)
public class SomeServiceImpl implements SomeService {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SomeServiceImpl.class);

    @Override
    public String doIt(String first, String second) {
        LOG.info("SomeServiceImpl: doIt(..)");
        return operation(first, second);
    }

    static String operation(String first, String second) {
        return first + second;
    }

    @Activate
    public void activate() {
        LOG.info("SomeServiceImpl: activate");
    }

    @Deactivate
    public void deactivate() {
        LOG.info("SomeServiceImpl: deactivate");
    }
}
```

And in my `build.gradle` I have:

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly 'org.osgi:osgi.annotation:7.0.0'
    compileOnly 'org.osgi:org.osgi.service.component.annotations:1.3.0'

    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.11'
    runtimeOnly 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:2.0.11'
    
    // ...
}
```

This is working as expected with slf4j `1.7.36`

Now with the version `2.0.11` of slf4j, because of usage of [service provider](https://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#bindingProviderDifference), there are new constraints modeled in the OSGi metadata and now I am stuck at:

```
Resolution failed. Capabilities satisfying the following requirements could not be found:
    [<<INITIAL>>]
      ⇒ osgi.identity: (osgi.identity=slf4j.simple)
          ⇒ [slf4j.simple version=2.0.11]
              ⇒ osgi.wiring.package: (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.slf4j)(version>=2.0.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))
                  ⇒ [slf4j.api version=2.0.11]
                      ⇒ osgi.extender: (&(osgi.extender=osgi.serviceloader.processor)(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))
```

It seems that I need an additional bundle, maybe provided by [SPI Fly](https://aries.apache.org/documentation/modules/spi-fly.html), but I could not understand how…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [example](https://github.com/apache/karaf/blob/karaf-2.x/jaas/modules/src/main/java/org/apache/karaf/jaas/modules/properties/PropertiesLoginModule.java#L120-L122) declares:

```
slf4j.api;version='[1.7.36,1.7.37)',\
slf4j.simple;version='[1.7.36,1.7.37)'
```

which is (I'm not a fan of gradle + OSGi + bnd) resolved to [slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar from Maven central](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.36/slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar).

This is proper OSGi bundle with:

```
Import-Package: org.slf4j.impl;version=1.6.0
Export-Package: org.slf4j;version=1.7.36, org.slf4j.spi;version=1.7.36
 , org.slf4j.helpers;version=1.7.36, org.slf4j.event;version=1.7.36
```

However [slf4j-api-2.0.11.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/2.0.11/slf4j-api-2.0.11.jar) has:

```
Require-Capability: osgi.extender;filter:="(&(osgi.extender=osgi.service
 loader.processor)(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))"
```

And indeed - it's satisfied by [Aries SPI-Fly](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/aries/spifly/org.apache.aries.spifly.dynamic.bundle/1.3.7/org.apache.aries.spifly.dynamic.bundle-1.3.7.jar) with:

```
Provide-Capability: osgi.extender;osgi.extender="osgi.serviceloader.re
 gistrar";version:Version="1.0",osgi.extender;osgi.extender="osgi.serv
 iceloader.processor";version:Version="1.0";uses:="org.apache.aries.sp
 ifly"
```

SLF4J got these headers (requirements) [in this commit](https://github.com/qos-ch/slf4j/commit/2235d3c69829caf19e38ea980a86042cc3ffd1f3).

SPI-Fly is OSGi's response to [Java Service Loader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html), transforming your bundle's code on the fly so proper thread context class loader is set.

This is actually a proper *requirement* from SLF4J API 2, because they switched from *static binding* of logger implementation to service discovery of `/META-INF/services/org.slf4j.spi.SLF4JServiceProvider` service.

However, OSGi is a tough beast. For logging I recommend [Pax Logging](https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.logging) project, which not only exports proper `org.slf4j` packages, but it also allows you to dynamically configure the logging backend and have it configured with OSGi Configuration admin.

Comment: Thank you, for now adding `runtimeOnly 'org.apache.aries.spifly:org.apache.aries.spifly.dynamic.bundle:1.3.7'` satisfies the requirement